# retrieve data using Ajax and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve data from multiple table. So when the user clicks and select an item php file to retrieve the data from the corresponding table.

this is my first try on Ajax used w3 school code and trying to modify, I guess the way I'm using if condition is the problem? Before I try with the multiple table it worked.

My Script

```
 <script>
function showUser(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "Please Select type of users to view";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","get_users.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
</script>
```

My Form

```
<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Staff</option>
<option value="2">Admin</option>
<option value="3">Customers</option>
</select>
</form>
```

My PHP Page

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','X','X','X');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con);

if ($q='Admin')
{

$sql="SELECT * FROM admin";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Mobile</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Password</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['mobile'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

else if ($q='Staff')
 {
echo "This is from Database B
}

else
{
echo "This is from database C";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: this is failing for 2 reasons `if ($q='Admin')` and this `else if ($q='Staff')` possibly 3 reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `$q = intval($_GET['q']);` with a string value for your assignments.

[`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) *"Get the integer value of a variable"*

```
<option value="1">Staff</option>
<option value="2">Admin</option>
<option value="3">Customers</option>
```

and using an [assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) rather than a [comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for both `if ($q='Admin')` and `else if ($q='Staff')` both being strings, as opposed to integers in your options.

which should read as and with 2 equal signs `if ($q=='2')` and `else if ($q=='1')` in order to match your select's numerical value options.

Or, change them accordingly with your options to read as `Staff` and `Admin` (and `Customers`) in the values, while removing the `intval()` from the GET array; the choice is yours.

You also don't need `mysqli_select_db($con);` since you've declared your 4 parameters in your initial connection and would fail for another reason; technically you didn't select a database for it.

You're also missing a quote and semi-colon in *(a parse syntax error)*

```
echo "This is from Database B
```

which should read as

```
echo "This is from Database B";
```

---

Footnotes:

The page which I believe you based yourself on, seems to be http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

If so, then I suggest you follow their example completely and modify it slowly to fit your needs. I myself have used that demo (in the distant past) before with success.

Their example uses a `WHERE` clause also.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";
```

---

Edit: Just for the record, there is a missing brace for this condition:

```
if ($q='Admin')
{
```

Comment: Thanks.
Also I have missed } in if condition. 

:-)

Comment: @CJM You're welcome, glad to have been of help, *cheers*. Edit: Yeah, I just spotted that now. My bad. Thanks for letting me know. I made an additional edit for it.